# Saving DataTable in state of "For Checker" On Maker-Checker Implementation Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, datatable

Here i would like to use Maker-Checker to a table in mssql database.
I planned to use DataTable Class documented on 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx

Now i Initialized a new Instance of DataTable as

```
DataTable Temp_Sample = new DataTable("Sample");
```

I hope to use

```
if(Checker.Approved(Temp_Sample, rowId)){Temp_Sample.AcceptChanges();}
if(Checker.Denied(Temp_Sample,rowId)){Temp_Sample.RejectChanges();}
```

I am stuck on How to Save and Fetch the Temp_Sample while waiting for Checker ie during "For Checker" state?

```
Temp_Sample.SaveWhileCheckerActionPerforms();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to Save and Fetch the Temp_Sample

For saving/persisting and fetching a `DataTable`, you have to use `Session` or `ViewStatse`.

Save your DataTable into session:

```
Session["DTSample"] = Temp_Sample; // Your DataTable saved in DTSample Session
```

Fetch your DataTable from Session:

```
// DtTemp DataTable will Fetch your DataTable from Session

DataTable DtTemp = (DataTable) Session["DTSample"];

// Do your work with DtTemp that contains your Temp_Sample DataTable
```